# Django CMS query to fetch data from tables

Tags: django

I have 3 tables which look like below:

```
class A(models.Model)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)

class B(models.Model)
   a =  models.ForeignKey('A')

class C(models.Model)
   b = models.ForeignKey('B')
```

I want to fetch all the rows from table C where B has values depending on a specific value of A.

For ex:

A has 2 rows:

Cricket

Football

B has 3 rows for each entry in A

C has 3 rows for each entry in B

so I want to fetch all the rows in C when A has value = 'Cricket'

How can I do this in a single Django query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think

```
C.objects.filter(b__a__title="Cricket")
```

should do the trick.